Forming incongruent triangles
Problem: There are n sticks of length $1, 2, 3, ..., n$. How many incongruent triangles can be formed by using three of the given sticks?
My solution: After solving the problem, I found the number of triangles, x, to be:
$$x=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left\lceil i \cdot \frac{i+1}{2} \right\rceil + 2 \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left\lceil \frac{i+1}{2} \right\rceil - \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left\lceil \frac{i+1}{2} \right\rceil^2 - n(n+1)
$$
However, I am not satisfied with this expression. Can it be simplified? (Can we express this equation without using the summation sign?)
N.B.: I encountered a similar question on stackoverflow, but it didn't include this equation, so I couldn't find my answer.

A suggestion:  write out the answers for the first dozen or so $n$, then search OEIS.  Seems very likely they know this sequence.  You might need to specify whether or not you allow "degenerate" triangles, like $(1,2,3)$.

Thanks for the suggestion. It might help."Thank you for the suggestion. It could be helpful."

https://oeis.org/A002623 ?

And a closed form appears to be $\left\lfloor \frac{1}{24}n (n-2)(2n-5) \right\rfloor$.

Could you please provide more details about it?

Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2504067/number-of-integer-sided-triangles ?

Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2032994/the-total-number-of-non-congruent-integer-sided-triangles-whose-sides-belong-to and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1988715/let-t-n-denote-the-no-of-integral-sided-triangles-with-distinct-sides-chosen and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3189586/n-incongruent-triangles-with-integer-sides-and-perimeter-n

@GerryMyerson Your first link is not a duplicate; the linked problem allows multiple edges with the same length, while this problem requires distinct edges. If you let $t_n$ be the answer to the linked question, and $s_n$ be the answer to this question ($s$ for "scalene"), then $t_n=s_{n+3}$. So, the answers are almost the same.

I will prove the following two formulae for the number of scalene triangles with side lengths in $\{1,\dots,n\}$. The first is
$$
 \frac12\binom n3 -\frac14\binom n2+ \frac14 \left\lfloor \frac n2\right\rfloor,\tag1
$$
and the second is
$$
 \frac{n(n-2)(2n-5)}{24}-\frac{1+(-1)^{n+1}}{16}.\tag2
$$
Let $\epsilon_n=(1+(-1)^{n+1})/16$. Formula $(2)$ says that $\frac{n(n-2)(2n-5)}{24}$ is equal to the number of triangles plus $\epsilon_n$. Since $0\le \epsilon_n\le 1/16$, this means the number of triangles is given by $\lfloor n(n-2)/(2n-5)/24\rfloor$.
Proof of formula 1
First, some terminology. Let $T_n$ be the set of unordered triples taken from $\{1,\dots,n\}$, so $|T_n|=\binom n3$.  I will always write my triples $\{a,b,c\}$ in sorted order, so $a<b<c$.
Let $\Delta_n$ be the set of triples in $T_n$ which define a triangle, so $\{a,b,c\}$ is in $\Delta_n$ when $a+b>c$.
Let $D_n$ be the set of triples in $T_n$ which define a degenerate triangle. That is, $\{a,b,c\}\in D_n$ whenever $a+b=c$.
I claim that
$$
|\Delta_n|=\frac{|T_n|-|D_n|}2=\frac12\left[\binom{n}3-|D_n|\right]\tag3
$$
The idea is this. If you take all of the triples in $T_n$, and set aside the degenerate triangles, then the remaining triples can be partitioned into pairs, where exactly one triple in each pair is a valid triangle. Specifically, for each $\{a,b,c\}\in T_n-D_n$,
$$
\{a,b,c\}\text{ is paired with }\{c-b,c-a,c\}.
$$
This works because $a+b>c$ if and only if $(c-b)+(c-a)<c$.
All that remains is to determine what $|D_n|$ is. Triples in $D_n$ looks like $\{a,c-a,c\}$, where $a<c-a$, meaning $a<c/2$. So, the question is, how many ordered pairs $\{a,c\}$ taken from $\{1,\dots,n\}$ satisfy $a<c/2$? There are $\binom n2$ pairs taken from $\{1,\dots,n\}$. If we set aside the pairs for which $a=c/2$, then exactly half of the remaining pairs will satisfy $a<c/2$. You can see this with another pairing argument; this time,
$$
\{a,c\}\text{ is paired with }\{c-a,c\}.
$$
The number of pairs set aside is equal to $\lfloor n/2\rfloor $, because we are setting aside the pairs $\{a,2a\}$ such that $2a\le n$. We have proved
$$
|D_n|=\frac12\left(\binom n2-\left\lfloor \frac n2\right\rfloor\right).\tag4
$$
Combining $(3)$ and $(4)$ proves $(1)$.
Proof of formula 2
In order to derive $(2)$ from $(1)$, use the equality
$$
 \left\lfloor \frac n2\right\rfloor =\frac n2 -\frac{1+(-1)^{n+1}}{4}
$$
and then do a lot of algebraic rearranging. You can prove the above equality in two cases, based on whether $n$ is even or odd.
